# Row iterator fails to sync with page iterator in Cassandra Pagination

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

I have a table "person" with 500 records.

```
int pageSize = 5;
Select selectStatement=QueryBuilder.select().from("person");
selectSt.setFetchSize(5);
ResultSet results = session.execute(selectStatement);
int pageCounter = 0;
// I need records that are in page 2 and page 3 only

while(!results.isExhausted())
{   
            if (results.getAvailableWithoutFetching() <= pageSize ) 
             {
                   pageCounter ++;

                   if(pageCounter == 2 || pageCounter == 3) {
                  //this is the code with issue where the records are printed from first row of page 1
                        Iterator<Row> rowsIterator = results.iterator();
                        while (rowsIterator.hasNext()) {
                            Row row = rowsIterator.next();
                            System.out.println("row:"+row);
                    }
              } 

              if(pageCounter>=3) break;

              if(!results.isFullyFetched())
                  results.fetchMoreResults()
}
```

I cannot take advantage of the token-based feature with Cassandra for pagination in my project which is a strict no.
The issue here is when I iterate through row iterator from the results; the row iterator actually starts to iterate from the first record of first page.
To get the records which are in page 2 and page 3, I unnecessarily have to iterate through every row this way. When i get the results from page 2 and page 3 and add them to the results, it is supposed to store only resultset from page 2 and page 3 and not from the first page to all the way to 100 pages.

Can anyone let me know what is that I am doing wrong? Is there a way to move the row iterator to 2nd page directly or any efficient method to do the same. I am stuck with this for couple of weeks now. Why is it that I have to iterate from first row of first page to get rows from page 2 and 3. Is this a drawback with Cassandra?

Thanks. Appreciate the help